# Searching a HashSet with regex

Tags: java, regex, hashset

There is a HashSet of strings and I want to search for key. The HashSet content looks like

```
AB
A1-A2-A3
A1
A2-A3
AD-A1
AZ
...
```

If I use `theSet.contains("A1")`, then it will return `A1` only. However, I want to get `A1-A2-A3` and `A1` and `AD-A1`. The special character in my data file is `-` which is the delimiter in case a line contains that.

If I don't use HashSet and search within an array of strings, then I know how to use `matcher()`. Any solution for the HashSet?

Comment: Just loop through the set, checking if each element matches

Comment: Remember that a HashSet is backed by a hashtable. This means that there is no concept of searching a HashSet.  You can only perform look-ups based on the known key you already have.  Using a regex implies you want to linearly scan the HashSet therefore you'll need iteration...there is no way around it.

Comment: [(.*-?A\d)](https://regex101.com/r/Lu1k9m/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no better solution than to iterate through the entire `HashSet` and run the matcher over each element.

```
for (String str : set) {
  if (str.contains("A1")) {
    // do whatever with str
  }
}
```

Comment: So, I just wanted to see it is possible to use the power of "time reduction" through HashSet for searching an array of strings.

Comment: This could return false positives, as it's not checking for the delimiter.

Comment: @mahmood: No.  It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try something like...

Take all the keys, and construct a very long ugly string

```
,AB,A1-A2-A3,A1,A2-A3,AD-A1,AZ,...
```

Then do a find all 'kind' of regex for A1:

```
uglystring = ",AB,A1-A2-A3,A1,A2-A3,AD-A1,"
thelist = re.findall("([^,]*A1[^,]*)", uglystring)
print (thelist)
```

That is in python.  Pretty ugly, but maybe get you going in the right direction?